# ionic cordova build android Multiple dex file error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to build an application using Ionic and when i perform

> ionic cordova build android

Furthermore i tried all the possible methods to solve this issue that are being listed under stackoverflow and ionicforums still end up with the same issue

i am getting this error as following. But the same code works fine if i perform a ionic cordova build ios

I am using the following plugins

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-document-viewer" spec="^0.9.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="^2.0.19" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

Error message :

> ✖ Running command - failed!
>
> [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
>           You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit
>   code 1):
>
> ```
>     (truncated) ... :generateDebugResValues
>     :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
>     :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
>     :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
>     :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
>     :CordovaLib:processDebugResources
>     :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
>     :CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>     :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>     :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution,
>     etc.).
>     Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>     Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>     :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>     :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
>     :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
>     :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
>     :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
>     :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
>     :CordovaLib:bundleDebug
>     :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>     :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
>     :CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
>     :CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
>     :CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
>     :CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
>     :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders
>     :CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders
>     :CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets
>     :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
>     :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
>     :CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>     :CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
>     :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
>     :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
>     :CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
>     :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
>     :CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>     :CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
>     :CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
>     :CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
>     :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>     :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution,
>     etc.).
>     Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>     Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>     :CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>     :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
>     :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
>     :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
>     :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
>     :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
>     :CordovaLib:bundleRelease
>     :prepareBarcodescannerLibrary
>     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
>     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
>     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
>     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
>     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library
>     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library
>     :prepareOrgApacheCordovaCordovaLib623DebugLibrary
>     :prepareDebugDependencies
>     :compileDebugAidl
>     :compileDebugRenderscript
>     :generateDebugBuildConfig
>     :generateDebugResValues
>     :generateDebugResources
>     :mergeDebugResources
>     :processDebugManifest
>     :processDebugResources
>     :generateDebugSources
>     :incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>     :compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>     :compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>     Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>     Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>     :compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>     :compileDebugSources
>     :mergeDebugShaders
>     :compileDebugShaders
>     :generateDebugAssets
>     :mergeDebugAssets
>     :transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>
>     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
>     * What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>     Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>
>     * Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
>     BUILD FAILED
>
>     Total time: 1 mins 16.804 secs
>     Error: /Users/adithya/Desktop/mobile-app/eImpact/platforms/android/gradlew:
> ```
>
> Command failed with exit code 1
>           Error output:
>           Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>           Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>           Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>           Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>           Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>           Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> ```
>     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
>     * What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>     Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>
>     * Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> ```

My dependency are as following

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Does anyone has the same issue, Thanks in advance

Comment: issue is being solved by downgrading the plugins

Comment: another solution which avoids needing to downgrade plugins: [cordova-android-support-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release)